# Windows XP Dual boot removal

Tags: windows, dual-boot, removing

I've had Ubuntu dual booted with Windows XP for awhile now and I think it's time to get rid of windows. How do I do this correctly so I don't mess up my hard drive?

Comment: What do you want to do with the space allocated for XP?

Comment: I'd like to add it to the space i have for Ubuntu if that's possible

Comment: The question is too general to answer beyond the usual: have a backup, make sure you know what you do before doing it. If you want a more detailed answer, please post your current partition layout.

Answer (score 2):

The general process for this process is:

- Ensure you have **all of your files backed up**
- Open GParted
- Identify your Windows partitions, often they will show as being mounted under /media or in a custom location if you specified so in your `/etc/fstab`.
  You can also match their sizes up to what you expect from what Windows reports
- Delete the partitions by right-clicking on there listings
- Expand your Ubuntu partion (will be mounted as `/`) by right-clicking it

We can provide better directions if we know more about your setup.
 Supplying us with `sudo fdisk -l` will allow us to try to identify your windows partition better

Comment: What do you mean by "match their sizes up.." in your 3rd bullet? Thanks!

Comment: If Windows reports your C: drive to be 60 GB, then GParted should report a partition with roughly the same size. They will be off slightly because one uses 1000MB=GB and the other uses 1024MB=GB

Answer (score 0):

Open the disk utility and find your windows partition 
format it to ext4 partition
[image]

Then open the the terminal and type

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: This seems pretty easy. But what happens to the unused space ? Should we use GParted or something like it or is there another way? Thanks!

Comment: unused space? this method. simply format winxp partition